# necesito comparar el resultado de una iteracion con selenium para enterarme de algun cambio en el contenido de la web

Tags: python, selenium

suponganmos que tenemos el sgt codigo

```
chrome_opcions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_opcions.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="F:\eglog\Proyectos\Panama\chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_opcions)
driver.get('www.helloworld.com')
elementos=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
for elem in elementos:
    p = elem.find_element_by_tag_name("a")
    print(p.text)
```

esto es lo que hace es iterar sobre todas la etuiquetas td y a su vez eccontrarme todos los textos de la etiqueta a que estan dentro de td
supongamos que el resultado de este ciclo for es el sgt
azul
amarillo
rojo
violeta
Lo que yo necesito es guardar ese resultado de tal manera que pueda compararlo cada cierto tiempo con el mismo y enterarme de que si en la web introdujeron una nueva etiqueta,,pense hacerlo por la cantidad de etiuquetas td pero sin resultado positivos por la cantidad nunca varia siempre son 4,lo que varia es el texto de esas etiquetas,,,es decir dentro de dos dias cambian azul por naranja y yo necesito enterarme,,,como enterarme lo tengo ya echo pero lo que no logro es la comparacion de la variable p,,necesito compararla con ese resultado de azul,amarillo,rojo,violeta y si existe un nuevo color enterarme,,como se haria esta comparacion

Comment: Si alguna de las respuestas aportadas soluciona tu problema, por favor, indicalo. Te recomiendo que sigas el https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour de stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que yo haria seria utilizar un assert sobre la lista. Creas una lista con los textos de los td y despues haces el assert con la anterior:

```
import unittest

l1 = [textotd1, textotd2]
for elem in elementos:
    p = elem.find_element_by_tag_name("a")
    l2.append(p.text)

unittest.TestCase().assertCountEqual(l1, l2)
unittest.TestCase().assertItemsEqual(l1, l2) # Solo disponible en Python 2.7
unittest.TestCase().assertListEqual( l1, l2) # Tambien valida el orden

l1=l2
l2=[]
```

Cuando los assert fallen es que la pagina ha cambiado

Answer (score 0):

Si los cambios tardan varios días yo almacenaría los resultados en un archivo o base de datos y re-compararía al volver a ejecutar.

Algo más o menos así:

```py
# Almacenar los resultados iniciales
with open('colores.txt', 'w') as outf:
    for elem in elementos:
        p = elem.find_element_by_tag_name("a")
        print(p.text)
        outf.write(p.text)

# Comparar resultados posteriores
colores = []
with open('colores.txt', 'r') as inf:
    for linea in inf:
        colores.append(linea)

# Luego para comparar
for i, elem in enumerate(elementos):
    p = elem.find_element_by_tag_name("a")
    print(p.text)
    if colores[i] != p.text:
        print("Cambio detectado. Valor original: %s - Valor nuevo: %s", % (colores[i], p.text))
```

Esto bajo el supuesto que el órden importa. Si el orden es irrelevante usa sets y evalua con un `if p.text in colores`.

Para que esto funcione vas a tener que implementar alguna lógica que te permita saber si el archivo de colores está vacio (ejecución inicial) o si ya tiene contenido listo para compararse.